# Unable to locate package libicu67

Tags: debian, docker

when I replace the deb sources with mirror address:

```
deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian/ buster main non-free contrib
deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian/ buster main non-free contrib
deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian-security buster/updates main
deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian-security buster/updates main
deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian/ buster-updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian/ buster-updates main non-free contrib
deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian/ buster-backports main non-free contrib
deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian/ buster-backports main non-free contrib
```

show error when build `Dockerfile` like this:

```
 => ERROR [ 4/15] RUN install_packages acl ca-certificates curl gzip libbsd0 libbz2-1.0 libc6 libedit2 libffi7 libgcc-s1 libgmp10 l  8.8s
------                                                                                                                                    
 > [ 4/15] RUN install_packages acl ca-certificates curl gzip libbsd0 libbz2-1.0 libc6 libedit2 libffi7 libgcc-s1 libgmp10 libgnutls30 libhogweed6 libicu67 libidn2-0 libldap-2.4-2 liblz4-1 liblzma5 libmd0 libncurses6 libnettle8 libp11-kit0 libpcre3 libreadline8 libsasl2-2 libsqlite3-0 libssl1.1 libstdc++6 libtasn1-6 libtinfo6 libunistring2 libuuid1 libxml2 libxslt1.1 libzstd1 locales procps tar zlib1g:         
#8 6.220 Reading package lists...                                                                                                         
#8 6.531 Building dependency tree...                                                                                                      
#8 6.665 E: Unable to locate package libicu67
#8 6.665 E: Unable to locate package libreadline8
#8 6.666 apt failed, retrying
#8 7.306 Reading package lists...
#8 7.609 Building dependency tree...
#8 7.731 E: Unable to locate package libicu67
#8 7.731 E: Unable to locate package libreadline8
#8 7.732 apt failed, retrying
#8 8.383 Reading package lists...
#8 8.681 Building dependency tree...
#8 8.801 E: Unable to locate package libicu67
#8 8.801 E: Unable to locate package libreadline8
```

why did this happen and what should I do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deb sources show Debian Buster (`oldstable`), but looking at [the Debian packages site](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libicu67), it seems that `libicu67` is only available for Debian Bullseye (`stable`) or Sid (`unstable`).  The situation for the missing `libreadline8` package [appears to be similar](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libreadline8).

You should be able to fix this in Docker by using a base image based on Debian Bullseye.